# Someone's trying to hack me, don't understand how they are bypassing my router, please help me understand?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, internet-security

```
Mar  5 00:39:44 deepcool sshd[259265]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=178.128.220.78  user=root
Mar  5 00:39:47 deepcool sshd[259265]: Failed password for invalid user root from 178.128.220.78 port 33500 ssh2
Mar  5 00:39:48 deepcool sshd[259265]: Received disconnect from 178.128.220.78 port 33500:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:39:48 deepcool sshd[259265]: Disconnected from invalid user root 178.128.220.78 port 33500 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:39:57 deepcool sshd[259288]: User root from 183.47.14.74 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:39:57 deepcool sshd[259288]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=183.47.14.74  user=root
Mar  5 00:39:59 deepcool sshd[259288]: Failed password for invalid user root from 183.47.14.74 port 47761 ssh2
Mar  5 00:40:00 deepcool sshd[259288]: Received disconnect from 183.47.14.74 port 47761:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:40:00 deepcool sshd[259288]: Disconnected from invalid user root 183.47.14.74 port 47761 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:40:17 deepcool sshd[259299]: User root from 62.4.16.39 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:40:17 deepcool sshd[259299]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=62.4.16.39  user=root
Mar  5 00:40:19 deepcool sshd[259299]: Failed password for invalid user root from 62.4.16.39 port 32980 ssh2
Mar  5 00:40:21 deepcool sshd[259299]: Received disconnect from 62.4.16.39 port 32980:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:40:21 deepcool sshd[259299]: Disconnected from invalid user root 62.4.16.39 port 32980 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:40:37 deepcool sshd[259311]: User root from 138.68.139.104 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:40:37 deepcool sshd[259311]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=138.68.139.104  user=root
Mar  5 00:40:39 deepcool sshd[259311]: Failed password for invalid user root from 138.68.139.104 port 58750 ssh2
Mar  5 00:40:40 deepcool sshd[259311]: Received disconnect from 138.68.139.104 port 58750:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:40:40 deepcool sshd[259311]: Disconnected from invalid user root 138.68.139.104 port 58750 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:41:18 deepcool sshd[259375]: User root from 47.91.106.208 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:41:18 deepcool sshd[259375]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=47.91.106.208  user=root
Mar  5 00:41:20 deepcool sshd[259375]: Failed password for invalid user root from 47.91.106.208 port 39690 ssh2
Mar  5 00:41:22 deepcool sshd[259375]: Received disconnect from 47.91.106.208 port 39690:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:41:22 deepcool sshd[259375]: Disconnected from invalid user root 47.91.106.208 port 39690 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:41:41 deepcool sshd[259485]: User root from 175.24.125.23 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:41:41 deepcool sshd[259485]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=175.24.125.23  user=root
Mar  5 00:41:42 deepcool sshd[259485]: Failed password for invalid user root from 175.24.125.23 port 43484 ssh2
Mar  5 00:41:44 deepcool sshd[259485]: Received disconnect from 175.24.125.23 port 43484:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:41:44 deepcool sshd[259485]: Disconnected from invalid user root 175.24.125.23 port 43484 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:41:50 deepcool sshd[259536]: User root from 134.175.59.225 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:41:50 deepcool sshd[259536]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=134.175.59.225  user=root
Mar  5 00:41:53 deepcool sshd[259536]: Failed password for invalid user root from 134.175.59.225 port 35164 ssh2
Mar  5 00:41:54 deepcool sshd[259536]: Received disconnect from 134.175.59.225 port 35164:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:41:54 deepcool sshd[259536]: Disconnected from invalid user root 134.175.59.225 port 35164 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:44:32 deepcool sshd[259772]: User root from 106.75.188.19 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:44:32 deepcool sshd[259772]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=106.75.188.19  user=root
Mar  5 00:44:34 deepcool sshd[259772]: Failed password for invalid user root from 106.75.188.19 port 55758 ssh2
Mar  5 00:44:36 deepcool sshd[259772]: Received disconnect from 106.75.188.19 port 55758:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:44:36 deepcool sshd[259772]: Disconnected from invalid user root 106.75.188.19 port 55758 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:44:45 deepcool sshd[259798]: User root from 47.91.106.208 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:44:45 deepcool sshd[259798]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=47.91.106.208  user=root
Mar  5 00:44:47 deepcool sshd[259798]: Failed password for invalid user root from 47.91.106.208 port 48074 ssh2
Mar  5 00:44:49 deepcool sshd[259798]: Received disconnect from 47.91.106.208 port 48074:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:44:49 deepcool sshd[259798]: Disconnected from invalid user root 47.91.106.208 port 48074 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:45:00 deepcool sshd[259818]: User root from 178.128.220.78 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:45:00 deepcool sshd[259818]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=178.128.220.78  user=root
Mar  5 00:45:02 deepcool sshd[259818]: Failed password for invalid user root from 178.128.220.78 port 45682 ssh2
Mar  5 00:45:03 deepcool sshd[259818]: Received disconnect from 178.128.220.78 port 45682:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:45:03 deepcool sshd[259818]: Disconnected from invalid user root 178.128.220.78 port 45682 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:45:21 deepcool sshd[259823]: User root from 212.64.65.2 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:45:21 deepcool sshd[259823]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=212.64.65.2  user=root
Mar  5 00:45:23 deepcool sshd[259823]: Failed password for invalid user root from 212.64.65.2 port 53300 ssh2
Mar  5 00:45:25 deepcool sshd[259823]: Received disconnect from 212.64.65.2 port 53300:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:45:25 deepcool sshd[259823]: Disconnected from invalid user root 212.64.65.2 port 53300 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:45:27 deepcool sshd[259827]: User root from 152.179.67.70 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:45:27 deepcool sshd[259827]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=152.179.67.70  user=root
Mar  5 00:45:30 deepcool sshd[259827]: Failed password for invalid user root from 152.179.67.70 port 2317 ssh2
Mar  5 00:45:31 deepcool sshd[259827]: Received disconnect from 152.179.67.70 port 2317:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:45:31 deepcool sshd[259827]: Disconnected from invalid user root 152.179.67.70 port 2317 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:46:21 deepcool sshd[259893]: User root from 62.4.16.39 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:46:21 deepcool sshd[259893]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=62.4.16.39  user=root
Mar  5 00:46:23 deepcool sshd[259893]: Failed password for invalid user root from 62.4.16.39 port 36470 ssh2
Mar  5 00:46:24 deepcool sshd[259893]: Received disconnect from 62.4.16.39 port 36470:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:46:24 deepcool sshd[259893]: Disconnected from invalid user root 62.4.16.39 port 36470 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:46:49 deepcool sshd[259924]: User root from 49.235.33.85 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:46:49 deepcool sshd[259924]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=49.235.33.85  user=root
Mar  5 00:46:51 deepcool sshd[259924]: Failed password for invalid user root from 49.235.33.85 port 34972 ssh2
Mar  5 00:46:51 deepcool sshd[259924]: Received disconnect from 49.235.33.85 port 34972:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:46:51 deepcool sshd[259924]: Disconnected from invalid user root 49.235.33.85 port 34972 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:48:19 deepcool sshd[260513]: User root from 47.91.106.208 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:48:19 deepcool sshd[260513]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=47.91.106.208  user=root
Mar  5 00:48:21 deepcool sshd[260513]: Failed password for invalid user root from 47.91.106.208 port 56456 ssh2
Mar  5 00:48:22 deepcool sshd[260513]: Received disconnect from 47.91.106.208 port 56456:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:48:22 deepcool sshd[260513]: Disconnected from invalid user root 47.91.106.208 port 56456 [preauth]
Mar  5 00:49:34 deepcool sshd[260702]: User root from 59.40.79.227 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Mar  5 00:49:34 deepcool sshd[260702]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=59.40.79.227  user=root
Mar  5 00:49:36 deepcool sshd[260702]: Failed password for invalid user root from 59.40.79.227 port 56604 ssh2
Mar  5 00:49:37 deepcool sshd[260702]: Received disconnect from 59.40.79.227 port 56604:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  5 00:49:37 deepcool sshd[260702]: Disconnected from invalid user root 59.40.79.227 port 56604 [preauth]
```

I have some software protection and am behind a router. What I don't understand is, how are these probes even reaching my machine behind the LAN? There are a couple of port forwards from the router to my machine, but these guys are targeting random ports and they seem to be reaching this specific machine. From my understanding of networks they should be denied at the router.

Why is this happening? What is this a symptom of? What do you recommend?

**edit:** Thank you all. I have most of the protections you recommended already enabled. I'm not forwarding port 22 on the router and ssh is using another port. What I really don't understand is these requests hitting my machine instead of... my printer/cellphones/laptops or just being blocked by the router. I'm actually considering buying a new router because of this as I think this one is compromised.

Comment: Is port 22 (ssh) one of the forwarded ports? Those port numbers in the log are the source ports on the remote computer (which is expected to be randomish), not the destination port (the one they're reaching you on).

Comment: “There are a couple of port forwards from the router to my machine, but these guys are targeting random ports and they seem to be reaching this specific machine.” - If you have forwarded port 22 to your machine then it’s accessible outside of your network.  If that isn’t what you want you should stop forwarding that port to your machine

Comment: Does your router have firewalling configured and enabled? If not, you shouldn't expect it to block traffic. Its job, unless told otherwise, is to make things "just work" as best as it can.

Comment: It is interesting that you use the term "router" instead of firewall.  Many people use a NATting firewall that will operate as a gateway (or "router") for internal computers while not permitting external (Internet sourced) traffic to reach them without a specific rule (e.g. port forwarding).  It is also possible to be issued a block of IP addresses, and actually route them without NAT or even a firewall.  Can you provide more detail on the network configuration?

Comment: @Slartibartfast it's a home router that gets the WAN that provides my home with a LAN/WIFI space. Pretty standard stuff. To access my personal computer from the outside I need to setup portforwarding. This is what I find weird about the situation.

Comment: You said "ssh is using another port" -- does that mean that there's a port forward set up (using something other than port 22) to an ssh server on your computer? If so, again, this is the expected result. If you have an ssh service accessible -- on *any* part, 22 or otherwise -- it will be found and attacked.

Answer (score 3):

For (many) years now, there are at least thousands, if not hundreds of thousands of bots (many of them belonging to botnets of machines that have already been hacked) that constantly scan public IPv4 space, looking for systems listening on popular admin ports like 22 (SSH) and 3389 (RDP).

If you have a box on one of these ports on public IPv4, you will get passively probed endlessly, the bots attempting to compromise your system by slowly brute forcing the password. If you have SSH password authentication disabled or a very strong password with symbols, you are mathematically safe, as the chances of them supplying the correct private key or password is virtually zero.

The main thing to be concerned about is OpenSSH server zero-days that allow remote code exploits. Those need to be patched immediately, as they are your biggest risk by exposing SSH on the public Internet.

As to why it's exposed, it could be any number of reasons. If you're forwarding a port range that includes port 22, that's why. Your router may also somehow be doing dynamic port forwarding, or your system may be configured to do UPnP to request the port to be opened. Unlikely, but it's possible.

Without providing details about exactly which router you have, how it's configured, which Linux system you have and how it's configured, it's impossible to know exactly why port 22 is being forwarded.

Comment: Best way to secure a machine with OpenSSH is to disable password authentication and only allow key authentication.  Obviously you have to also use a secure appropriate sized key certificate.  This won’t stop the blind attempts, but honestly, changing the port number is pointless (checking every port doesn’t take much time).  Changing the port is security through obscurity, which is the worst type of security

Comment: My answer does not recommend changing the port number. The reason I mentioned the port is because the OP doesn’t understand why his SSH port is open to the Internet to begin with, since his box is behind a NAT gateway. I was speculating as to why that could be the case.

Comment: Also, key based authentication and using a very strong password are almost indistinguishable in terms of their resistance to being compromised by these brute force bots. Threats attacking the client can still compromise either a key or a password; they just have to access a different mechanism on the client (the keyboard/clipboard for a password; the file system for a key).

Comment: I only recommend key authentication due to the fact they are already getting probed and because most users don’t use a strong password

Answer (score 2):

you can put a crontab to block the IPs tryng to hack your server, it must be run each 10 minutes

##line in crontab
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/tools/anti_hacking.sh > /dev/null 2>&1

#### and this is my script

srvftp01:/usr/bin/tools> cat anti_hacking.sh
DESTINATARIO="your-email@domain.com"
FECHA=$(date '+%b %d %H:%M:%S') && FECHA_PREV=$(date --date '-10 min' '+%b %d %H:%M:%S')
#echo $FECHA_PREV && echo $FECHA

TIME_INICIAL=`echo $FECHA_PREV | cut -c1-11`
TIME_FINAL=`echo $FECHA   | cut -c1-11`

#echo $TIME_INICIAL $TIME_FINAL

###when they try guess root password
EN_RIESGO=`cat /var/log/secure | grep "Failed password for root"| egrep "$TIME_INICIAL|$TIME_FINAL" | wc -l`
if [ $EN_RIESGO  -gt "0" ]; then
echo "Se ha producido un intento de adivinar clave de root en `hostname`, favor validar desde $FECHA_PREV hasta $FECHA"
cat /var/log/secure | grep "Failed password for root"| egrep "$TIME_INICIAL|$TIME_FINAL" > /tmp/hackeo1.txt
cat /var/log/secure | grep "Failed password for root"| egrep "$TIME_INICIAL|$TIME_FINAL" | awk '{print "sshd: "$11}' >> /tmp/hackeo1.txt
cat /var/log/secure | grep "Failed password for root"| egrep "$TIME_INICIAL|$TIME_FINAL" | awk '{print "sshd: "$11}' >> /etc/hosts.deny
/bin/mutt -e 'set realname='SEGURIDAD''  -e 'my_hdr Importance: high' -e 'my_hdr From:seguridad@domain.com'  -s "Importante: Se ha producido un intento de adivinar clave de root en `hostname`, favor validar desde $FECHA_PREV hasta $FECHA" $DESTINATARIO < /tmp/hackeo1.txt
else
echo "todo OK #1"
fi

###when they try to hack unknown user account
EN_RIESGO=`cat /var/log/secure | grep "Failed password for invalid user"| egrep "$TIME_INICIAL|$TIME_FINAL" | wc -l`
if [ $EN_RIESGO  -gt "0" ]; then
echo "Se ha producido un intento de adivinar clave de root en `hostname`, favor validar desde $FECHA_PREV hasta $FECHA"
cat /var/log/secure | grep "Failed password for invalid user"| egrep "$TIME_INICIAL|$TIME_FINAL" > /tmp/hackeo2.txt
cat /var/log/secure | grep "Failed password for invalid user"| egrep "$TIME_INICIAL|$TIME_FINAL" | awk '{print "sshd: "$13}' >> /tmp/hackeo2.txt
cat /var/log/secure | grep "Failed password for invalid user"| egrep "$TIME_INICIAL|$TIME_FINAL" | awk '{print "sshd: "$13}' >> /etc/hosts.deny
/bin/mutt -e 'set realname='SEGURIDAD''  -e 'my_hdr Importance: high' -e 'my_hdr From:seguridad@domain.com'  -s "Importante: Se ha producido un intento de acceder a `hostname`, favor validar desde $FECHA_PREV hasta $FECHA" $DESTINATARIO < /tmp/hackeo2.txt
else
echo "todo OK #2"
fi

EN_RIESGO=`cat /var/log/secure | grep "error: PAM: Authentication failure for root"| egrep "$TIME_INICIAL|$TIME_FINAL" | wc -l`
if [ $EN_RIESGO  -gt "0" ]; then
echo "Se ha producido un intento de adivinar la clave de root, favor validar desde $FECHA_PREV hasta $FECHA"
cat /var/log/secure | grep "error: PAM: Authentication failure for root" | egrep "$TIME_INICIAL|$TIME_FINAL" >> /tmp/hackeo3.txt
/bin/mutt -e 'set realname='SEGURIDAD''  -e 'my_hdr Importance: high' -e 'my_hdr From:seguridad@domain.com'  -s "Importante: Se ha producido un intento de adivinar la clave de root en `hostname` favor validar desde $FECHA_PREV hasta $FECHA" $DESTINATARIO < /tmp/hackeo3.txt
else
echo "todo OK #3"
fi

#### EOF

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you the following solution:

1. Change your SSH port to something else in the higher range (above 10000).
2. Install `fail2ban` and set up SSH protection. It will blacklist the remote IP address of the bot after a set number of fails.
3. User level protection: disable root login in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, set up a regular user (non-superuser) on your Linux box with low credentials for remote login and use `sudo` with a command or `su` or `sudo -i` to get a root shell.
4. Set up a strong password. Use a proper hash generator with a variety of lower-case, upper-case letters, numbers and punctuations.

Optionally: if you always log in from a set of static IP addresses, make a whitelist of them in a `.txt` file, e.g. `trusted-ssh-addresses.txt`, close the ssh port and generate opening rules for each IP address by a script.

Comment: Password authentication isn’t secure on a machine that is remotely accessible.  It should be disabled and a certificate should be used instead.  Changing the port number is just security through obscurity which is the worst type of security

Comment: (1) The problem with certificates is that they have to be saved on the client side. If the client is a portable device and gets stolen or somebody creates an image copy of its storage device, they can manage to gain access to the remote server as well. (2) Changing the port number is not a security measure. It's goal is to reduce the number of bots hitting the standard SSH port and bloating the log. (3) A strong password with 16+ characters (that you can remember of) is virtually unbreakable remotely.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

- Check how old is the router's firmware and update if possible. Old firmware can hold many exploits.
- Check if you haven't configured DMZ to your computer IP address.
- Check if you are not using port address translation (part of nat). For example external port 12345 mapped to ComputerInternalIP:SSHdPort.
- From an external computer scan all your opened ports: `sudo nmap -sV -A YourExternalIPAddress`.
- `fail2ban` may help but from your log the source never repeats and the frequency of attempts is low.
- Disconnect every device from your network except for the computer and router. Connect one by one and check logs. You may have a rogue device just forwarding packets. Unfortunately if the frequency is too low it would be difficult to perceive. You can also try using a packet sniffer.
- Use a firewall or repurpose an old computer with firewall software (pfsense for example).

They are not targeting random ports, the attempts reached SSHd. The ports on the log are the ports used to reply.

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume this situation is associated with spam and blackmail emails as well. Real freakin nice… bunch of crooks passing malicious information off as advice via forums.  Absolutely terrible. AND doing it cryptically just to screw with people.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1199317)